# accessing n values from json objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var list=[
{
    color_1: "red",
    color_2: "red_1",
    value: "#f00"
},
{
    color_1: "green",
    color_2: "red_5",
    value: "#0f0"
},
{
    color_1: "blue",
    color_2: "red",
    value: "#00f"
},
{
    color_1: "cyan",
    color_2: "red",
    value: "#0ff"
},
{
    color_1: "magenta",
    color_2: "red",
    value: "#f0f"
},
{
    color_1: "yellow",
    color_2: "red",
    value: "#ff0"
},
{
    color_1: "black",
    color_2: "red",
    value: "#000"
}
```

];

in my json list i am getting dyanamic columns from back end like color_1,color_2,color_3,color_4....color_n upto n number of columns in json objects, i want to print them on console using for loop ,but i am getting undefined as output could you please tell me where i am getting wrong below is code

function callMe(){

```
    list.forEach(function(element, i) {
    for(var j=1;j<3;j++){

            console.log(element.color_+j);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a proper [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) with brackets and a string.

```
console.log(element['color_' + j]);
```

```js
function callMe() {
    list.forEach(function(element, i) {
        for (var j = 1; j < 3; j++) {           // var instead of int
            console.log(element['color_' + j]); // brackets
        }
    });
}

var list = [{ color_1: "red", color_2: "red_1", value: "#f00" }, { color_1: "green", color_2: "red_5", value: "#0f0" }, { color_1: "blue", color_2: "red", value: "#00f" }, { color_1: "cyan", color_2: "red", value: "#0ff" }, { color_1: "magenta", color_2: "red", value: "#f0f" }, { color_1: "yellow", color_2: "red", value: "#ff0" }, { color_1: "black", color_2: "red", value: "#000" }];

callMe();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `console.log(element["color_"+j])`

Hope that helps!

Comment: typo ! `console.log(element["color_"+j])` (no dot)

Comment: right thanks Pierre

Answer (score 0):

To access an entry with a computed key you should use square brackets like this:

```
console.log(element[“color_”+j]);
```

The way you tried first gets `element.color_` which is undefined, then adds `j` to undefined.